# Vuetify calendar height issues

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, height

I'm trying to prevent two scroll bars appearing when using Vuetify's sheet and calendar.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container fluid class="fill-height">
        <v-row justify="center" class="fill-height">
          <v-col cols="12" class="fill-height">
            <v-sheet class="fill-height">
              <v-calendar type="week" />
            </v-sheet>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you update this [codepen](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/gOmZpKM) to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: [Updated](https://codepen.io/dillonm197/pen/RwpEWqj)
The `type` of the calendar needs to be set to `week` or `day`.

Comment: In your demo, the scrollbars only appear when scrolling, which doesn't quite match your screenshot, where they're always shown. What am I missing?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I looked at the codepen and I can see two scrollbars. I'm trying to make it so there is only one scrollbar.
I updated the screenshot above.

Comment: Odd. I don't see the scrollbars in my browser (Chrome 91 on macOS BigSur): [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/aiy0iPL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just override the CSS of Vuetify Calendar Component to remove a redundant scroll-bar:

```
.v-calendar-daily__scroll-area {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Also remove the `class="fill-height"` from the `v-sheet` , it make a bit overlap for calendar. I don't know why you added it.

Check it out here:
https://codepen.io/nmdatit/pen/OJpdwox
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! I'm looking to make the calendar fit the remaining content of the page and scroll only from the scroll area.

Comment: I know. But set it for only one parent container is enough ;)